# Calculating Age without using a function in the where clause

Tags: sql-server, function, date, t-sql, where-clause

I have been reading about avoiding using functions in the WHERE clause (as they often have to use scans and are generally not very efficient).

I have an SP that calculates a customers age based on whether they've had a birthday in the last few days.

I am struggling to move my calculation of the birthday from the where clause into the select statement.  This is the current SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_CalculateAge (
@LastNDays int
) AS
        UPDATE Customers
           SET CustomerAge = DATEDIFF (yy, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE ())
         WHERE DATEADD (yy, DATEDIFF (yy, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE ()), CustomerBirthDate) BETWEEN
            DATEADD (dd, ISNULL (@LastNDays, -4), GETDATE ()) AND GETDATE ();
```

I'm happy with the ages it is creating. Looking at other advice, I can also calculate AGE by doing the following

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, CustomerBirthDate, getdate()) + CASE WHEN (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year, CustomerBirthDate, getdate()) , CustomerBirthDate) > getdate()) THEN - 1 ELSE 0 END
      from customers'
```

My problem is I'm now unsure where I can put the section that searches to see if the birthday has occurred in the last 4 days.  I can only think of it in the WHERE clause & not in the SELECT.

```
BETWEEN
            DATEADD (dd, ISNULL (@LastNDays, -4), GETDATE ()) AND GETDATE ();
```

I'm assuming I need some kind of CASE statement, or an IF.

Currently, this is running through every customer, every time...I want to specifically only run it for those with birthdays in the last N days.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [CustomerFirstName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerBirthDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CustomerAge] [smallint] NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Customers_CustomerBirthDate] ON [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [CustomerBirthDate] ASC
)

INCLUDE([CustomerID],[CustomerFirstName],[CustomerAge])
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerFirstName],[CustomerBirthDate])
VALUES('Stephen', '2000-11-14'),
('Sarah', '1980-11-15'),
('Zoe', '1965-01-01')
```

Based on this, if we were to run the code, it would add CustomerAge to Stephen and Sarah but leave Zoe NULL.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Stephen

Comment: don't waste time calculating age, because it is never correct. Create a computed column which does your function thing and you will always have correct age

Comment: Also you dont want to use function in where clause (which is correct it is not great for performance) but if you do the calculations/logic in where clause anyway it is just like using a function.

Comment: Agree. Your should not store columns that need constant updating. Replacing it with a calculated column like `CustomerAge AS <calculation>` is preferable. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z653szrC).  If replacing the column is not an option, I would not worry too much about the table scan. One table scan on the customers table per day is not a performance killer.

Comment: ...Although a once-daily table scan is not a concern, you might want to limit the actual updates applied, if there are any triggers or change tracking that could be impacted. This can be done by using a `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the updated value and adding a `WHERE` to limit update to just those rows having changes. Something like `UPDATE C SET CustomerAge = A.CalculatedAge FROM Customers C CROSS APPLY (SELECT CalculatedAge = ...) A WHERE C.CustomerAge <> A.CalculatedAge OR C.CustomerAge IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers you've been given above are mostly valid, however, personally I very much dislike having computed columns, whether they are directly defined within the table definition, or whether they are maintained by virtue of a job. I dislike the former because they make for awkward indexing - in order to index a computed column you need to make it persisted, which means the column needs to be recalculated any time you update the values in the table, and I dislike the latter because they are reliant on a job.

If your objective is simply to make your age calculation work with the `WHERE` clause you're asking about, I think this should do the job for you, and should be properly indexable as well:

```
DECLARE @LastNDays INT = 4

CREATE TABLE #Customers
(
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [CustomerFirstName] [varchar] (30) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerBirthDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Customers ([CustomerFirstName], [CustomerBirthDate])
VALUES
('Stephen', '2000-11-14'),
('Sarah', '1980-11-17'),
('Zoe', '1965-01-01')

SELECT
    CustomerFirstName,
    CustomerBirthDate,
    DATEDIFF(YY, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE()) + (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE()), CustomerBirthDate) > GETDATE() THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS CustomerAge,
    DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE()), CustomerBirthDate)) AS DaysSinceLastBirthDate
FROM #Customers
WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, CustomerBirthDate, GETDATE()), CustomerBirthDate)) BETWEEN -@LastNDays AND 0

DROP TABLE #Customers
``
```

Comment: You'd still need to recalculate the data every day, because `GETDATE()` changes constantly...

Comment: You're getting the current age at the time of running the query. You aren't storing anything, so there isn't anything to update.

Comment: you don't *need* to persist a computed column for indexing unless it's float i think.

Comment: @siggermannen, computed columns can only be indexed without persisting if they are deterministic. GETDATE() is not a deterministic function. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver16#built-in-function-determinism for the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive example using CTEs to acquire 3 previous days for a requested number of previous years.  You could create a stored procedure that does the same thing with parameters.  The CTE's output a list of valid dates going back so many years so if your birthday column is indexed then it should be sargable.

I'll use 2 CTE's, the first gets 3 prior days.  The second CTE recursively goes back 150 years (assuming nobody lives that long) to select the 3 prior days of those 150 years.

```
--Create DDL
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers (
 customer_id int IDENTITY(1,1)
,birthday datetime
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncx_Customers_birthday ON dbo.Customers(birthday)

INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (birthday) VALUES
 ('1975-12-15'), ('1980-12-17'), ('1992-04-25'), ('2022-02-05'), ('2013-07-06')
,('1982-12-03'), ('2000-12-04'), ('2002-12-02')

------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @checkdate datetime = '2023-12-05';
DECLARE @yearsAgo tinyint = 150
DECLARE @stopHistory datetime = DATEADD(YEAR, -@yearsAgo, @checkdate);

WITH CTE3priordays AS (
 SELECT @checkdate AS [checkdate]
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @checkdate) 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -2, @checkdate)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -3, @checkdate)
)

,CTE_150prioryears AS (
 SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, checkdate) AS [byYears]
   FROM CTE3priordays
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, byYears) AS [byYears]
   FROM CTE_150prioryears
  WHERE byYears >= @stopHistory
)

SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Customers
 WHERE birthday IN (
--The recursive list of dates
SELECT byYears 
  FROM CTE_150prioryears 
)
OPTION(maxrecursion 700) 
--covering 3 days prior for 150 years produces 601 rows, hence we need maxrecursion
```

Would produce example output:

```
customer_id birthday
----------- ------------------------
6           1982-12-03 00:00:00.000
7           2000-12-04 00:00:00.000
8           2002-12-02 00:00:00.000
```

Which appears to be what you're after.